# Which are the homomorphisms between the two groups $G=Z/(3)$ and $H=Z/(5)$?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Given two groups $G$ and $H$, there is at least one homomorphism between them, namely the trivial homomorphism: $f:G\rightarrow H, \ f(x)=e_{H}, \forall x\in G.$ To specify a homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow H$ you just have to specify an element $h\in H$ to be the image of $e_{G}$ and any choice of $h$ gives you a well defined homomorphism. So there are |H| many homomorphisms $G\rightarrow H.$ But i just read in a book that for $G=Z/(3)$ and $H=Z/(5)$ there can be defined only the trivial homomorphism, which i dont understand. It is also not quite clear, what $Z/(3)$ means. I presume though that it means $Z/3Z.$

Can somebody comment on why between these two groups there can be defined only the trivial homomorphism and no other one ? Thanks for any comment.

Answer (score 1):

Let's recall a few results. Let $\phi : G \to H$ be a group homomorphism, where $G, H$ are finite. Then:

- $\text{ker}(\phi)$ is a subgroup of $G$. So $|\text{ker}(\phi)|$ divides $|G|$.
- $\text{Im}(\phi)$ is a subgroup of $H$, so $|\text{Im}(\phi)|$ divides $|H|$
- $G/\text{ker}(\phi) \cong \text{Im}(\phi)$. Thus, $|G| = |\text{ker}(\phi)| * |\text{Im}(\phi)|$. In particular, $|\text{Im}(\phi)|$ divides $|G|$.

Now here we have $G = \mathbb{Z}_{3}$ and $H = \mathbb{Z}_{5}$. So $|\text{Im}(\phi)| \in \{1, 5\}$ by the second bullet point, and $|\text{Im}(\phi)| \in \{ 1, 3\}$ by the third bullet point. Thus, $|\text{Im}(\phi)| = 1$, which implies that $\phi$ is trivial.

Comment: Thanks. Very clear and very convincing.

Comment: In the case where at least one of the groups $G, H$ has infinite order, i assume that this method would not apply any more. Am i correct ?

Comment: That is correct?

Comment: Let $f:Z\rightarrow H, \ H $ of finite order. Then there are  2 |H| many surjective homomorphisms between $Z$ and $H.$ The factor $2$ comes from the fact that there are $2$ generators of Z. To get the total number of homomorphisms between $Z$ and $H$, this number must be augmented by the number of divisors of |H| to account for the number of non surjective homomorphisms and according to your previous explanation. Am I correct or still missing something ?

Comment: By $Z$, do you mean the integers? If so, $\mathbb{Z}$ (viewed as an additive group) is cyclic with generator $1$. The homomorphic image of a cyclic group is cyclic. So if $H$ is not cyclic, then $f$ is certainly not subjective.

Comment: Yes, I mean the integers. So following what you are saying, it means that things are more complicated than i thought. Can we then state the following: a. If $H$ is cyclic (i.e. if $f$ is surjective) and of finite order, then the number of homomorphisms is $2|H|$. b. If $H$ is not cyclic, then the number of homomorphisms is equal to the number of divisors of $H$ ? In the case the domain group is not cyclic, must we then sum up the number of surjective homomorphisms and divisors of the order of the codomain group to get the total number of homomorphisms ?

Comment: Where are you getting these conjectures from? Have you made some attempt to work through them? I would suggest spending some time with them. Counting homomorphisms is not a trivial task. By the way, $H$ being cyclic is a necessary but not sufficient condition for $f$ to be subjective. Consider the trivial homomorphism as a counterexample.

Comment: $Z$ has  two generators as cyclic group (viewed as an additive group), 1, -1. In the case $f$ is surjective and because $f$ is determined by the Image of the generator of $Z$, it follows that there are at most $2|H|$ surjcetive homomorphisms. In the case $f$ is not surjective, the range of each homomorphism must satisfy the rules which you explained at the beginning concerning the order of $H$. Am i still missing something ?

Comment: A cyclic group is a group $G$ where there exists some $g \in G$ s.t. $G = \langle g \rangle$. In the case of the integers, $1$ is a cyclic generator.

Comment: Sure, but -1 is also a generator since each element of $Z$ can be written as sum of a combination of $1's$ and $-1's$.

Comment: Observe that $-1 = 1^{-1}$. You really need not consider $-1$ As a generator.

Comment: Sure since in the case of $Z$ the inverse of a generator is a generator. What are then the consequences in terms of the number of homomorphisms i was talking above ? It was in these terms that i did talk about generators. Hopefully we will stop then here.

Comment: If you want to open a new thread on this topic, I’ll be happy to compose an answer there. My answer is likely too long for a comment.

Comment: Sure. Since i am new to the world of stack exchange, I don't know how to procede in order to open a new thread. Please do it. I really want and need to know, how to grasp the nature of homomorphisms through the understanding of their quantity between two groups. I will highly appreciate that. Let me know how to acces that thread. Many thanks.

Comment: Hit the "Ask Question" link at the top. :-)

Comment: I just did it. Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi:G\to H$ be a homomorphism. We must send $0$ to $0$. So all that remains is to specify where to send $1$ and $2$. Let $\phi(1)=a\in H$. Since $3=0$ in $G$, $\phi(3)=\phi(0)$, so $\phi(1)+\phi(1)+\phi(1)=3a=0_H$. But this can only happen if $a=0_H$. It follows that $\phi(2)=\phi(1)+\phi(1)=0_H$.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's very clear. Your answer is complementing the one of @mlo105 very well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, yes, $\mathbb{Z}/(n)=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and, yes, there is no non-trivial group homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

Now, why do you say that “To specify a homomorphism $f\colon G\longrightarrow H$ you just have to specify an element $h\in H$ to be the image of $e_G$ and any choice of $h$ gives you a well defined homomorphism”? The image of $e_G$ can only be $e_H$.

Comment: Thanks. It is clear but i still have some doubt. Let $f:Z\rightarrow Z$ be a map. How many endomorphisms of $Z$ exist ? According to your answer, there can be only 4 endomrphisms, i.e. $f(1)=1, f(1)=-1, f(-1)=1$ and $f(-1)=-1,$ for each endomorphism respectively. By coincidence or not they are all isomorphisms. Can you give me an example of an homomorphism other than the trivial one and which is not an isomorphism ?

Comment: @user249018 What I wrote was that $f(0)$ can only be $0$. For every $n\in\mathbb N$, the map $a\mapsto na$ is an endomorphism of $\mathbb Z$

Comment: I think now i know the difficulty which arose. By $e_{G}$ i meant the generator of $G$. I am sorry i was not clear enough. Let $f: Z\rightarrow H.$ Do you then agree that there are 2 |H| many homomorphisms between $Z$ and $H$ or i am still missing something? The factor two comes from the fact that there are 2 generators of $Z.$ I also assume that $H$ has finite order.

Comment: @user249018 Yes, you are right. But your notation is not standard.

Comment: I am sorry for the inappropriate notation. Now the last answer (2|H| homomorphisms) would make sense only if all the homomorphisms were surjective. But a homomorphism must not be surjective. In the latter case a homomorphism must satisfy what was previously commented by @mlo105, i.e. the total number of homomorphisms must be augmented by the number of divisors of |H|. So there must be then more than 2|H| homomorphisms! Am i still missing something ?

Comment: @user249018 It's more complex than that. For instance, there are two and only two homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z$ into $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that, if $A$ is a commutative ring, $I$ an ideal of $A$ and $M$ is an $A$-module, then
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}\Hom(A/I,M)\simeq 0:_M I.$$
Apply this to the abelian group (= $\mathbf Z$-modules) $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$ and the ideal $3\mathbf Z$:
$$\Hom(\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z,\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z)\simeq 0:_{\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z}3\mathbf Z. $$
Now, in $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$, multiplication by $3$ is invertible since $3$ and $5$ are coprime, so the annihilator of $3\mathbf Z$ in $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$ is $0$,  and 
$$\Hom(\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z,\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z)=\{0\}.$$