# Characterizing Homomorphisms between two Groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $f: G\rightarrow H$ be a group-homomorphism, $G$ and $H$ might be of **finite or infinite order**. I need to explore **orders of these groups, numbers of homomorphisms between them, their relation to the respective generators** (in the case one or both of them are cyclic), the **possibilities of being surjective, injective or not... What kind of **relations** can one observe and conclude between these notions ?

To my understanding there are $2|H|$ many surjective homomorphisms between $G=Z$ and $H$, where $H$ is supposed of finite order. The factor $2$ comes from the fact that there are 2 generators of $Z$. To get the total number of homomorphisms between $Z$ and $H$ this number must be augmented by the number of divisors of $|H|$ to account for the number of non surjective homomorphisms. 
Many thanks for any comment.

Comment: While I have not downvoted your post, I suspect you are getting downvoted for asking a very broad question without evidence of thought or effort at resolving this. I have found that targeted questions with evidence of effort are generally received better on help forums than broad questions with no demonstrated efforts.

Comment: As I mentioned in our previous discussion, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic group, which means it is generated by a single element: $\mathbb{Z} \cong \langle 1 \rangle$. Nailing down the single generator $1$ is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing our discussion from [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571083/which-are-the-homomorphisms-between-the-two-groups-g-z-3-and-h-z-5/2571089) Suppose $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and $H$ is a finite cyclic group. So $H \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ (i.e., the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$) for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. We consider homomorphisms of the form $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_{n}$.

Now since $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is a quotient group, we have a natural projection map $\pi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ sending $\pi(x) = \overline{x}$. That is, $\pi$ sends an element to its congruence class in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$. So $\pi$ is one such surjective homomorphism. There are other surjective homomorphisms $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ as well. We note that $\phi$ is surjective if and only if $\phi(1)$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$. How many generators are there for $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$?

**Lemma:** Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ (it is safe to assume $n \geq 2$), and let $k \in \{0, \ldots, n-1\}$. Then $\overline{k}$ has order $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ if and only if $\text{gcd}(k, n) = 1$.

**Proof:** Exercise for the reader.

**Remark:** How many elements less than $n$ are also relatively prime to $n$?

So now we consider homomorphisms of the form $\tau : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ that are not surjective. So $\text{Im}(\tau)$ is a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$. So what do the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ look like?

**Lemma:** Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. For every positive divisor $d|n$, there exists a subgroup $H \leq \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ of order $d$. Furthermore, $H$ is unique and $H$ is cyclic.

**Proof:** Exercise for the reader.

So if $\tau$ is not surjective onto $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$, $\tau$ is certainly surjective onto $\mathbb{Z}_{d}$ for some divisor $d|n$. So we now reduce to the case of counting surjective homomorphisms onto $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ for arbitrary $n$. I will leave this for you to work through.

Note that in general, enumerating group homomorphisms and isomorphisms is quite challenging. Deciding if two finite groups of the same order are isomorphic doesn't appear to be polynomial time solvable. The best known bounds aren't much better than $n^{\log_{2}(n)}$, which is an easy to show worst case. For arbitrary relational structures (e.g., graphs), deciding if there even exists a homomorphism is often times NP-Complete (see Constraint Satisfaction Problems). You should be willing to put in a lot of work if you want to enumerate homomorphisms with specific properties. In light of this last paragraph, you should not expect easy answers in general to a lot of the questions in your OP.

Comment: Thanks. In conclusion and following the premises of the nature of the two groups, #(homomorphisms $Z\rightarrow Z_n$, surjective +non-surjective)$=\phi (n)+$#$(i:d_i|n)$, where $\phi $ is the Euler function. At the forelast pragraphe you are probably asserting that this remains true for $n\in N$ and not $n=\infty$ Correct ? How about considering a more general case where $H$ is not supposed cyclic ? Can you draw some some general lines ?

Comment: Your comment is not legible. Also, lifting to the case of arbitrary finite Abelian groups takes work, and you’ll want more finite group theory under your belt than I suspect you currently have (e.g., the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups). Again, this is not an easy problem.